# Do light conditions affect writing?

Tags: creative-writing, tools

I've started to notice that I do a lot more writing at night, with my lights off. When I write with a light on, I get a slight migraine, and I'm not sure why.

So do different lighting conditions affect how people write, and am I the only one who writes better with the lights off?

Comment: Is light actually effecting your *writing*, or is it simply *causing* a headache due to writing with the lights on? ie, does some other similar task also produce a headache with the lights on?

Comment: No, I only get a headache when I try to write with my computer on.

Comment: You may have a refresh conflict between your light bulb and your monitor. If your monitor cycles at (I'm picking a number) 60Hz and your bulb is 65Hz, the resultant flicker may cause eyestrain. Try (a) a different bulb (b) a different *kind* of bulb, like changing incandescent to LED (c) a different light source/lamp (d) moving the lamp to somewhere else in the room, e.g., so it reflects off a wall rather than sitting next to you (e) different light conditions, like daylight, firelight, or candelight (f) a glare shield on your monitor.

Comment: I think this question is not about writing but about the effect of light on human physiology or psychology during night time work and should be asked on another site.

Comment: A doctor may be able to address the headache aspect of this.  You could try your primary provider and you could also consult an eye doctor.  While you're waiting for your appointment, you could start to notice things like your blinking rate and the frequency of interruptions (from others or from yourself) that would get you looking off-screen, if only briefly.

Comment: It's depending on your mood, and also in the night you feel active if you are not sleepy.

Comment: @what I think that even though this isn't specifically about writing, it still has to do with the tools and environment for writing.  This no different than asking "what software do I use for...." except it is "what is better lights on or off for writing?"  I don't really see the difference between the 2 personally.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this question belongs on this site, however:

Psychologically for introverts, night time is a period of isolation due to silence and the fact that you have the reassurance of light (your computer screen) against our natural fear of darkness. Also, as light doesn't fluctuate like it does in the day - some people find it easier to concentrate. It varies from person to person, however working at night may allow you to:

1. *Focus better* due to the lack of distractions
2. *Have more time to think*, as you're not noticing the natural shift in time.
3. *Concentrate more* due to the only visible objects being your screen

Personally, I prefer writing at night due to these reasons - however be warned that due to the ['blue light syndrome'](http://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/blue-light-has-a-dark-side) it may not be very healthy.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, migraines are a part of staring at a bright screen too long too often.  This wasn't an issue for me 10 years ago because most of my time was spent doing high school sports and only used a PC on the weekend for home work.  As I became more and more dependent on my PC for all my needs, my eyes started to deteriorate faster.  With website conventions forming to the google and apple motto of a clean professional look, more websites are going to the white background.  Top that off with looking at a white word document and having bright lights on around you, that strains the eyes quite a bit.....  I wouldn't suggest completely turning off the lights though as the screen brightness would definitely hurt the eyes more but I do agree that darker rooms/night time is where I typically write my best.

A suggestion to help with the eyes is to get a pair of yellow computer glasses.  The yellow tint helps offset the white screens you see on a PC for hours and creates less strain on the eyes.  Less strain means less likely to get a headache.  This would help you write longer and concentrate on something other than your head hurting.  I would also suggest looking at the applications you use to switch to a dark theme.  For example, my programming software I use comes with a white page.  They have the option to change the theme so that the background turns black/dark grey and the colors of the words are changed so you can read them against a dark background.  There are also plugins in Chrome like TLV that you can toggle on and off to make websites like SE have a black background for easier reading.

so yes, I do believe that the conditions of lighting affects how well/long we can focus before getting a headache and proper protection of the eyes should be taken for long term computer usage.